# get black screen after small kernel update ubuntu 12.04

Tags: 12.04, drivers, kernel, updates

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [My computer boots to a black screen, what options do I have to fix it?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/162075/my-computer-boots-to-a-black-screen-what-options-do-i-have-to-fix-it)

So I dit an update of ubuntu 12.04 today and after I restarted the pc I get a black screen and I can't do anything. The updates seemed like hotfixes for the kernel update size 8kb 
And during the installation I saw that ubuntu tried to activate the 304-310 beta NVIDIA driver. Any way to solve this without reinstalling ubuntu?